# programmatically add remove items from resource dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm just new in wpf and am planning to use a listbox to generate recently opened or closed items. Everytime a file is opened, it gets added permanently added into a resource dictionary of type listbox item.

On the other hand, besides the listbox item is a button to remove the link.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ResourceDictionary is a `IDictionary`. You can use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms601221.aspx) to add/override items.

`myResourceDictionary["somekey"] = someObject;`

And you can use the [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms521848.aspx) and [Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms521863.aspx) method.

As for your scenario I would prefer to use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms668604.aspx) instead and [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/cc163299.aspx) your listbox to it.

Comment: +1 for binding to an ObservableCollection: that's the wpf way after all

Comment: Can we add items to ResourceDictionary that is declared as merged dictionary wtih Source property set ?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible and, in addition to bitbonk's answer, I would say this:

You probably *don't* want to have an `ObservableCollection` filled with `ListBoxItems`.  `ListBoxItem` is a class that WPF uses for rendering and you'd not typically create these yourself.  If you make your data source a collection of (for example) `FileInfo` objects, you can use data templates to make the display of those items in the list appear however you wish.  This also has the benefit that you don't have to write code transform your data objects into a separate class just for display purposes.

(You'd likely use your own data/model type rather than `FileInfo`, but I don't know enough about your solution to suggest one.)